# Variable is "undefined" when used in a different method?

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

I have this code for the setup of an object:

```
myObj.prototype.__init = function(a, b, c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

And then in another function I want to use the `a` I setup in the `__init` method:

```
myObj.prototype.myFunc = function(){
    var data = parse(a);
        //...
}
```

The problem is that `a` is `undefined`. I also tried `this.a` and it results `undefined` too. The funny thing is that a `console.log(myO)` after doing a `var myO = new myObj();` and `myO.__init(myA, myB, myC);` prints the object with the field `a` initialized. How do I access then `a` inside that function of my object?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the call to myFunc:

```
someVar = new tccHandler.myObj();
someVar.__init(myA, myB, myC);
someVar.myFunc();
```

Comment: You should be able to access it as `this.a` -- I suspect your `this` is getting changed.  Please show the call to `myFunc`.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I edited the question and added the call to `myFunc`.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't exactly match what you originally posted (this is the first sighting of `tccHandler`).  Please post the code that creates `myObj` / `tccHandler.myObj`.

Comment: It doesn't match because it's nodeJS, I imported a file via `var tccHandler = require('my/path');`. In that file I stored all the code that adds function to the prototype of `myObj`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it should be `parse(this.a)`.

Remember that *properties* of `this` are *not* in the lookup-chain for identifiers [read: variables] by default; only lexical *variables* and properties of "the global object" (i.e. `window`) are.

`a` is a *variable* in the function `__init` (as a function parameter), where the object it names is assigned to the *property* `this.a`, but `a` is *not* a variable of the function `myFunc`. Each function introduces it's *own* lexical scope.

Happy coding!

Comment: @Masiar `this.a` *inside* `myFunc` evaluates to undefined? The *only* way that is, with the above code, is if `myA` evaluated to undefined when `__init` was invoked. In any case, just a plain `a` inside `myFunc` will *never* work and *will*  show the observed behavior for the given code.

Comment: @Masiar Remember that when you test `this.a` it has to be *from within the correct context* (e.g. it won't work from the console) where `this` has been "bound" to the appropriate object.

Comment: @Masiar: This does indeed work. If you're having trouble, it's something you haven't shown us. Check out this JSFiddle for proof: http://jsfiddle.net/p6Qv5/3/

Comment: I checked `myA` within `__init` and it indeed prints the correct value with `console.log(this.a)` after assigning it. It's really strange that then, in `myFunc`, if I do the same console log I get `undefined`. I'll investigate over this and let you know what I discover. Otherwise thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In normal javascript, you would do:

```
myObj = function(a,b,c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

Demo:

```
> var x = new myObj(1,2,3);
> x.a;
1
```